# I am not able to check if there is data in variable in laravel 6 with count() collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am not able to check if there is data in the variable in laravel 6. Here is the function. Here the problem is `$tags->count()` is not hitting else statement

```
public function index(){

    $tags = Constant_model::getDataAllWithLimit('tags',"id",'DESC',50);

    if ($tags->count() >0) {

        $data = array(
            'title'=>'All Tags',
            'description'=>'All Tags',
            'seo_keywords'=>'All Tags',
            'tags'=>$tags
        );

        return view('tags',$data); 

    }else{
        $data = array(
            'title'=>"Page Not found",
            'description'=>"Page not found",
            'seo_keywords'=>'',
            );

            return view('404',$data);
    }
}
```

Here is getDataAllWithLimit function

```
public static function getDataAllWithLimit($table,$order_column,$order_type,$limit){
    $data = DB::table("$table")->orderBy("$order_column", "$order_type")
      ->paginate($limit);
      return $data;
  }
```

Comment: plz remove the quote from the variable...

Comment: @TsaiKoga which one?

Comment: `DB::table("$table")` - That will still work, PHP extrapolates variables inside of double quotes, but it's not necessary, `DB::table($table)` is cleaner.

Comment: 1) $data = DB::table("$table")->orderBy("$order_column", "$order_type") should be $data = DB::table($table)->orderBy($order_column, $order_type)

Comment: I am able to fetch data! not able to perform if else statement

Comment: Have you see any error reporting?

Comment: `dd($tags)` to see the results? Can you even `count()` a paginated result? Won't that always be > 0, since it has `total`, `per_page`, `last_page` etc?

Comment: @kerbholz yes getting issue when i am using paginate()

Comment: getting this with dd($tags) - Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#332 ▼
  #total: 128
  #lastPage: 3
  #items: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#275 ▶}
  #perPage: 50
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}

Comment: It seems currentPage is 1, and perPage: 50, so the count is 50, greater than 0, so it will not hit the else statement.

Comment: Error with this - if ($tags->total >0) {

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was totally wrong, you can in fact `->count()` pagination results. This will get the number of items for the current page. If you want to count all items it's `if ($tags->total() >0) {`

Comment: ->count() not working... frustration now

Comment: are you sure your collection has no return to went trough in else statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and hope it helps...

```
    if (count($tags->toArray()['data']) > 0) {

    $data = array(
        'title'=>'All Tags',
        'description'=>'All Tags',
        'seo_keywords'=>'All Tags',
        'tags'=>$tags
    );

    return view('tags',$data); 

}else{
    $data = array(
        'title'=>"Page Not found",
        'description'=>"Page not found",
        'seo_keywords'=>'',
        );

        return view('404',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use PHP's [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count all the elements.

```php
public function index()
{
    $tags = Constant_model::getDataAllWithLimit('tags', 'id', 'DESC', 50);

    if (count($tags) > 0) {

        $data = array(
            'title' => 'All Tags',
            'description' => 'All Tags',
            'seo_keywords' => 'All Tags',
            'tags' => $tags
        );

        return view('tags', $data);
    }

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'Page Not found',
        'description' => 'Page not found',
        'seo_keywords' => '',
    );

    return view('404', $data);
}
```

```php
public function getDataAllWithLimit($table, $order_column, $order_type, $limit)
{
    return DB::table($table)->orderBy($order_column, $order_type)->paginate($limit);
}
```